# Factored Joint Distribution of Tree Augmented Naive Bayes Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes

I asked this question at Mathoverflow but they recommend me to ask here. I need to find factored joint distribution of [Tree Augmented Naive Bayes](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~nir/Abstracts/FrGG1.html) algorithm. I read the paper but I couldn't figure out the answer. Any help or pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where $A_1$, $A_2$, ..., $A_n$ are the attribute variables and $C$ is the class variable, it's:

$P(C) \prod_{i=1}^{n} P(A_i | A_{\pi(i)}, C)$.

Where $\pi(i)$ is the index of the parent of $A_i$ in the tree or $0$ if $i$ is the root and $P(A_i | A_0, C)$ is defined to be $P(A_i | C)$.